# Create conda environment offline

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have Anaconda installed on a RedHat-6.5 environment that is not connected to the Internet.

Is it possible to create a conda environment based on the existing Anaconda install, or minimal python packages?

FYI: I was able to clone a conda environment that already exists:

```
conda create -n dummy --clone my_env --offline
```

Comment: The `--offline` flag should work to install any package that is already cached in the `pkgs` directory (i.e., already installed by conda at some point).

Answer (score 5):

You could try cloning root which is the base env.

`conda create -n yourenvname --clone root`

With the env created you can install packages like these

`conda install packagename --offline`

Comment: Where will conda get the package from when using --offline?  Is there a specific directory on computer it looks in?

Comment: What if I want another version of python? I guess the python version would be same in your way.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a basic bash script I've used to clone without `conda` attempting to download or compare anything:

```
orig_env=/path/to/envs/orig
clone_env=/other/path/to/envs/clone

mkdir -p $clone_env
cp -r $orig_env/ $clone_env/

cd $clone_env
grep -rI "$orig_env"
# cd to the folders with references to the old folder name
sed -i -e "s:$orig_env:$clone_env:g" *

source activate $clone_env
conda info
```

The sed command finds the shebang at the top of files that reference specific locations for copies of python and fixes them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learned from your post that conda envs work if locally copied. In my case, conda was broken (couldn't find library files etc - after I removed sth in the base environment). I can rescue my old environments now through: `mv ~/miniconda3 ~/miniconda3_old`; then installing new miniconda into ~/miniconda3; and then just copying the old envs to my new envs - all envs are then rescued. Thanks a lot! I tried many hours with cloning but I realized conda clone environments be it with yml or not is NOT reliable at all! condaHTTPError and openblas not found errors. horrible.You saved me!

Comment: since the paths after copying should be practically exactly the same like before moving out, I have not to even correct the paths.